# Syntax help: Function pointer surrounded by square brackets

Tags: c++11, function-pointers

I'm confused about the use of square brackets around [funcParam] in the C++11 code segment below:

```
typedef std::function<std::vector<OtherType> ()> FuncPtr;

inline void create(FuncPtr funcParam)
{
    auto create_evaluator = [funcParam] ()
    {
        return anotherFunction(funcParam());
    };
    // ...
}
```

The code above it called by this line (somewhat simplified to keep it readable):

```
create( [] () { return CONSTANT; } );
```

Can someone explain the use of brackets in both situations? In the calling code, it looks to be used to create a function without a name. What's it doing in the first segment? Thanks!

Comment: This is called lambda-expression. Google "C++ 11 lambda" and you will find plenty of information.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! (Very hard to search for this without "lambda").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_evaluator` is a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (check out the examples at the bottom of that page).

In the case of

```
auto create_evaluator = [funcParam] ()
{
    return anotherFunction(funcParam());
};
```

- `[funcParam]` is a variable in the local scope that is captured by the lambda function and therefore available to be reference within the lambda function when it is called elsewhere.
- `()` denotes the arguments to the lambda function (none in this case)
- `{ return anotherFunction(funcParam()); }` is the body of the lambda function.

With the call

```
create( [] () { return CONSTANT; } );
```

`create` is called with another lambda expression as its argument. That lambda argument

- captures nothing: `[]`
- has no arguments: `()`
- has the body: `{ return CONSTANT; }`